# Alternatives to setting encoding in FileWriter - Java

Tags: java, encoding, outputstream, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I read that java documentation for FileWriter - it doesn't allow us to specify encoding. I'm using FileWriter in order to avoid the newline character that gets automatically appended while writing list of strings to a file(And I think this is the only thing I can use to achieve that).

I'm now facing a problem that some japanese characters in few properties file are written as "???", so I need to pass in the encoding information somehow. Is there any other way to either avoid the newline appending or a way to pass encooding info to FileWriter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `FileWriter`, but instead `new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), encoding)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with `Path` (Java 7+), you can use `Files.newBufferedWriter(path, charset, options)` to specify a `Charset`.  (This also wraps your output in a `BufferedWriter`, which is nice.)

The classic alternative is to use `OutputStreamWriter` and pass a `Charset` that way.

Always passing a charset to writers is a good habit, even if you don't think it's likely to ever deal with non-ASCII content.

Comment: But I think newBufferedWriter would append a system-specific newline as EOL which I'm trying to avoid.  BufferedWriter() does that , not sure if newBufferedWriter behaves differently w.r.t this.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I know that BufferedWriter supports newLine() to add platform-specific newline, but I thought if you wrote a literal \n, that would get used. Is that not the behavior you see?

Comment: I don't want to add a platform-specific newline. BufferedWriter does exactly that. I want to preserve the newline that's in the source text file.  But now I tested OutputStreamWriter and it worked! :-) didn't add newlines and also allowed to specify encoding!